# QGIS: evis -- trying to use url rather than a path

Tags: qgis-3, photos

QGIS 3.2 Mac OS 10.13.5

I have just added some photos to my project using importphoto to generate the layer and evis to view them.

I am now trying to get my photos independent of hard coded paths on my computer to make it much easier access the project from the 'Net.

To this end I have installed apache on the database server and have it serving the photos from an indexed directory and this works fine from the browser.

I first tried putting `http://localhost:1812/gis_photos` in the relative section and ticked the relative box in the path section.   From the docs I believe that this should take the filename from the path and append it to the url and then retrieve the resulting url.  I get no errors and no photo, just the metadata displayed.

I then tried editing the layer attributes to put the url in the path field with the same result.

Apache logs show no access attempts which suggests that the url is not being accessed at all.

Update:  I have logged an [issue](http://issues.qgis.org/issues/19450).

Further update:  This is a bug and it was present in 2.18 and therefore will have to wait before being fixed.